# Service Unavailable 503, PHP

Tags: wordpress, openshift

Hi my wordpress site keeps showing a 503 error repeatedly and it annoying, can you help me out?

My url alerts-thewatchmencrew.rhcloud.com

I have tried reducing the load of plugins and i also increased the php memory limit to 368 megs, but nothing is working.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some server logs or more details?

Comment: I just pulled this error from my log. It appears quite often. [error] [client 127.7.221.1] File does not exist: /var/lib/openshift/55bdbaa60c1e6663c30001d6/app-root/runtime/repo/php/2015
54.176.171.245 - -

Comment: here is another error - [error] (14)Bad address: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Sat Aug 08 02:07:23 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c3,c963

Comment: One More - [error] [client 127.7.221.1] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_mime_magic: read failed: /var/lib/openshift/55bdbaa60c1e6663c30001d6/app-root/runtime/repo/php/wp-content/plugins/wp-symposium-toolbar/fonts/WPST-icons.ttf, referer: http://alerts-thewatchmencrew.rhcloud.com/2015/08/07/httpwww-rt-comnews311914-privacy-glasses-japan-facial-recognitionutm_sourcerssutm_mediumrssutm_campaignrss/?utm_campaign=news&utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitter
66.102.8.154 - -

Comment: The site will be working one minute then down the next.

Answer (score 0):

IP 66.102.8.154 [appears to be a Google Proxy](https://www.abuseipdb.com/whois/66.102.8.154), which would suggest your site / server is being hit by repeated http requests from that IP.  This can lead to server overloaf / high resource usage on the server, which in turn leads to the site appearing to be "down".

An interesting question is why this Google Proxy is hitting your server - you can read more about Google Proxy here which does not provide definitive answer, but does offer some possible theories;  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47113/is-this-google-proxy-a-fake-crawler-google-proxy-66-249-81-131-google-com/49521#49521